# How to translate Views header syntax? not Title

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

In a view, i have filter content using "Language". it works fine. i have added "header" contain HTML syntax (which will be shown with top of view) like:
`<div class="xyz">Text need to translate</div>`
i couldn't translate this syntax.

can anyone suggest how it will be translate??

Comment: can it be seen under translate page?

Comment: Yes. but when i translate, it gives error like `HTML syntax translation not allowed`

Comment: Are you using the i18n views module?

Comment: yes using i18n views moduke

Comment: Have you enabled translation for the HTML filter?  It's off by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to translate expressions containing HTML code:

1. Go to `admin/config/regional/i18n/strings`
2. Check "full HTML" in "Translatable text formats" section
3. Then, go to `admin/config/regional/translate/i18n_string`
4. Click on "Refresh strings".